# PHP value date xlsx to csv

Tags: php, date, csv, phpexcel, xlsx

I have an XLSX file with some cells that has a date value like: 13/04/2015 when I convert my XLSX to CSV the date value in my CSV becomes its value as: 42107

I need that the value be the same in both files like in XLSX (13/04/2015)

Here's my convert script

```
include ('./PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
$TypeFile="Excel2007";
$FilePath= "./assets/uploads/files/prf.xlsx";
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($TypeFile);
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);   
$objExcel = $objReader->load($FilePath);
$objCSV = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objExcel, 'CSV');
$objCSV->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
$objCSV->setDelimiter(','); 
$objCSV->setEnclosure('"');    
$objCSV->save('./assets/uploads/files/prf.csv');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will

A date in MS Excel is a number value like 42107, that represents a number of days since 1st January 1900, and the only thing that tells MS Excel (or PHPExcel) that it should be treated as a date is the number format mask that's applied to that cell.

When you use

```
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
```

you're telling PHPExcel to read the raw data values from the cells, and ignore any number format masks (or indeed any styling) for cells, so that's what you're getting.

If you want PHPExcel to treat the value as a date, then don't use `$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);`